# Can not fetch the value from array using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I am unable to fetch some value as per some condition using angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
 var subcategories = [{
            id:1,
            name: 'SubCategory 1',
            value: 1
          }, {
            id:2,
            name: 'SubCategory 2',
            value: 2
          }, {
            id:3,
            name: 'SubCategory 3',
            value: 3
          }, {
            id:4,
            name: 'SubCategory 4',
            value: 4
          }];
    var result = $filter('filter')(subcategories, {id:1})[0];
    console.log('result',result);
```

Here i need to fetch all data whose `id=1` from `subcategories` object. But in console i am getting result `undefined`. Please help me.

Comment: This code works as expected. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T6AWJPpu561tZgzRIfsO?p=preview) with your code that shows it working.

Comment: duplicate maybe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851571/how-to-filter-by-a-specific-field-in-an-object-array-using-filterfilter

Comment: It would probably be easier to do `subcategories.filter(sub => sub.id === 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Code works. Did you import the $filter directive into your controller??

https://jsfiddle.net/naLqezvs/

```
function Controller($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.subcategories = [{
        id:1,
        name: 'SubCategory 1',
        value: 1
      }, {
        id:2,
        name: 'SubCategory 2',
        value: 2
      }, {
        id:3,
        name: 'SubCategory 3',
        value: 3
      }, {
        id:4,
        name: 'SubCategory 4',
        value: 4
      }];
  $scope.results = $filter('filter')($scope.subcategories, {id:1});
  $scope.result = $scope.results[0];
}
```

Comment: "But in console i am getting result undefined." If OP didn't inject `$filter` his code would probably fail with TypeError.